# Incorrect size of several tables in a database with PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm investigating why the database of one of my clients is getting slower and slower. I've discovered that PhpMyAdmin is measuring many tables in the database with an incorrect size value. In example, there is one table that actually weights 0,77 Mb, while PhpMyAdmin measures it with a size of 22.3 Mb. I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with the velocity of my client's website, but just in case... Any idea about why PhpMyAdmin is doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: what engine to you use for that table ?

Comment: How have you determined the table's "actual weight" of 0,77Mb?